# how to write in properties file without deleting old values

Tags: java, properties-file

I want to write in properties file without removing earlier written values in file.
for Eg there is value in properties file

```
token = tokengenerated
```

Now when I again set new value like

```
token1 = tokensnew
```

Then the properties file should show

```
token = tokengenerated
token1 = tokensnew
```

Comment: First read the file, then afdd the properties  and then write the file

Comment: So your question is how to add new property values and have them saved to the same property file? Or do you actually want to have only one key "token" that you can set with a new value without losing the original value? In the latter case using a default properties file may be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass true as a second argument to FileWriter to turn on "append" mode.

fout = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);

[FileWriter usage reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

You should read file and update it through properties and streams.

below is the code snippet is help you.

```
public class ReadAndWriteProperties {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        String propertiesFileName = "config.properties";
        File f = new File(propertiesFileName);
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);

        if (input != null) {
            props.load(input);
            props.setProperty("token2", "tokensnew");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            props.store(out, "save");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must read the file (var1), then add your content to the var1 and then write the var1 to the file.